# How to find/remove unused dependencies in Gradle

Tags: java, maven, gradle, dependency-management

I wanted to find unused dependencies in my project. Is there a feature for this in Gradle, like in Maven?

Comment: Update 2022/08/17 - Gradle 7.2 - AS Chipmunk: I find this plugin works: https://github.com/autonomousapps/dependency-analysis-android-gradle-plugin

Answer (score 90):

### UPDATE for Kotlin Users: 17 December 2021: Detects missing or superfluous build dependencies in Kotlin projects : Version 1.0.9 (latest)

I have added 2 types of configuration for Kotlin users.

- Using the plugins DSL
- Using legacy plugin application

**Using the plugins DSL:**

```
plugins {
  id("com.faire.gradle.analyze") version "1.0.9"
}
```

**Using legacy plugin application:**

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    maven {
      url = uri("https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/")
    }
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath("com.faire.gradle:gradle-kotlin-buildozer:1.0.9")
  }
}

apply(plugin = "com.faire.gradle.analyze")
```

**Resource Link:**

1. https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.faire.gradle.analyze
2. https://github.com/Faire/gradle-kotlin-buildozer
3. https://discuss.gradle.org/t/detecting-unused-projects-dependencies/25522

### UPDATE: 28-06-2016: Android support to unused-dependency

> In **June, 2017**, they have released the `4.0.0 version`
> and renamed the root project name `"gradle-lint-plugin"` to
> `"nebula-lint-plugin"`. They have also added **Android support to
> unused-dependency**.

---

In **May 2016** Gradle has implemented the [Gradle lint plugin](https://github.com/nebula-plugins/gradle-lint-plugin) for finding and removing unwanted dependency

### [Gradle Lint Plugin: Full Documentation](https://github.com/nebula-plugins/gradle-lint-plugin/wiki)

> The Gradle Lint plugin is a pluggable and configurable linter tool for
> identifying and reporting on patterns of misuse or deprecations in
> Gradle scripts and related files.

This plugin has various rules. [Unused Dependency Rule](https://github.com/nebula-plugins/gradle-lint-plugin/wiki/Unused-Dependency-Rule) is one of them. It has three specific characteristics.

1. Removes unused dependencies.
2. Promotes transitive dependencies that are used directly by your code
   to explicit first order dependencies.
3. Relocates dependencies to the 'correct' configuration.

To apply the rule, add:

```
gradleLint.rules += 'unused-dependency'
```

Details of [Unused Dependency Rule](https://github.com/nebula-plugins/gradle-lint-plugin/wiki/Unused-Dependency-Rule) is given in the last part.

**To apply the Gradle lint plugin:**

```
buildscript { repositories { jcenter() } }
plugins {
  id 'nebula.lint' version '0.30.2'
}
```

**Alternatively:**

```
buildscript {
  repositories { jcenter() }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.netflix.nebula:gradle-lint-plugin:latest.release'
  }
}

apply plugin: 'nebula.lint'
```

**Define which rules you would like to lint against:**

```
gradleLint.rules = ['all-dependency'] // Add as many rules here as you'd like
```

For an enterprise build, we recommend defining the lint rules in a init.gradle script or in a Gradle script that is included via the Gradle apply from mechanism.

For multimodule projects, we recommend applying the plugin in an `allprojects` block:

```
allprojects {
  apply plugin: 'nebula.lint'
  gradleLint.rules = ['all-dependency'] // Add as many rules here as you'd like
}
```

---

---

### Details of [Unused Dependency Rule](https://github.com/nebula-plugins/gradle-lint-plugin/wiki/Unused-Dependency-Rule) is given in this part

To apply the rule, add:

```
gradleLint.rules += 'unused-dependency'
```

The rule inspects compiled binaries emanating from your project's [source sets](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#N14E7A) looking for class references and matches those references to the dependencies that you have declared in your [dependencies](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#N15632) block.

### Specifically, the rule makes the following adjustments to dependencies:

#### 1. Removes unused dependencies

- Family-style jars like com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk are removed, as
  they don't contain any code

#### 2. Promotes transitive dependencies that are used directly by your code to explicit first order dependencies

- This has the side effect of breaking up family style JAR files, like
  com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk, into the parts that you are actually
  using, and adding those as first order dependencies

#### 3. Relocates dependencies to the 'correct' configuration

- Webjars are moved to the runtime configuration
- JAR files that don't contain any classes *and* content outside of META-INF are
  moved to runtime
- 'xerces', 'xercesImpl', 'xml-apis' should always be runtime scoped
- Service providers (JAR files containing META-INF/services) like
  mysql-connector-java are moved to runtime if there isn't any provable
  compile-time reference
- Dependencies are moved to the highest source set configuration
  possible. For example, 'junit' is relocated to testCompile unless
  there is an explicit dependency on it in the main source set (rare).

---

---

### UPDATE: Previous plugins

For your kind information, I want to share about previous plugins

1. The Gradle plugin that finds unused dependencies, declared and transitive is [com.github.nullstress.dependency-analysis](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.github.nullstress.dependency-analysis)

But **its latest version 1.0.3 is created 23 December 2014**. After that there aren't any updates.

> N.B: Many of our engineers are being confused about [this plugin](https://github.com/wfhartford/gradle-dependency-analyze) as they
> updated only the version number, nothing else.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is not compatible with latest changes in Android/gradle. Instead of telling me which dependencies I can dispose of, the plugin tells me to add dependencies and replace other dependencies with the deprecated `compile` instead of `implementation`.

Comment: This plugin sadly doesn't work with the kotlin dsl. They have no plans to support it.

Comment: It also doesn't work with the new gradle configurations (eg: `implementation` and `api`), and even worse, recommends changing from the new ones to the old deprecated ones (eg: `compile`, `testCompile`, etc.).

Comment: @SkyWalker you seem to have not read my comment at all.... 

>This plugin sadly doesn't work with the kotlin dsl. They have no plans to support it.

Comment: For 2020: https://www.baeldung.com/gradle-finding-unused-dependencies

Comment: Also, doesn't work for kotlin based gradle files (August 2020)

Comment: Still doesn't work with Kotlin-based files.

Comment: @snowe, I have updated for kotlin-based projects. please check.

Comment: @sigma1510, I have updated for kotlin-based projects. please check.

Comment: `gradle-lint-plugin` or nebula-plugin doesnt work for Android project, (Source)[https://github.com/nebula-plugins/gradle-lint-plugin/issues/36#issuecomment-884790846]

Answer (score 21):

I just learned about this one: https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.autonomousapps.dependency-analysis

[Github](https://github.com/autonomousapps/dependency-analysis-android-gradle-plugin)

From the looks it is under active development, but I haven't tested it yet.

Edit:
Actually it is pretty awesome, it provides lots of advises (e.g. whether to use api vs implementation)

Comment: I would go for this one, I've got so much better results, thanks

Comment: Can confirm, this one is excellent, and unlike others also works for kotlin-based gradle files.

Answer (score 9):

The project mentioned in the earlier answers seem to be dead. I use [gradle-dependency-analyze](https://github.com/wfhartford/gradle-dependency-analyze). Setup is simple:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'ca.cutterslade.gradle:gradle-dependency-analyze:1.0.3'
  }
}

apply plugin: 'ca.cutterslade.analyze'
```

Then do:

```
$ gradle analyzeDependencies
```

Comment: I am facing this error: 'Gradle sync failed: Task with name 'classes' not found in project'

Comment: I get stackOverflowException doing that. No precise information what is causing this though. I think there might be a circular dependency issue here but it would be a great idea I the tool told me where.

Comment: @Pawan this plugin doesn't work with Android projects, and this isn't going to change anytime soon. Proof: https://github.com/wfhartford/gradle-dependency-analyze/issues/18

Answer (score 8):

I've had a lot of luck using the [Gradle Dependency Analysis Plugin](https://github.com/NullStress/gradle-dependency-analysis-plugin).  To get started with it, add the following two things to your Gradle build script.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.github.nullstress:DependencyAnalysisPlugin:1.0.3"
    }
}
```

and

```
apply plugin: "dependencyAnalysis"
```

Once those are in place, run `gradle analyze`.  If there are unused dependencies, you'll get a build failure that shows output similar to the text below, plus a list of the unused dependencies (both declared and transitive).  The build failure is really handy if you want to enforce that there should be no unused dependencies via a CI build.

```
:foo:analyze FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':foo:analyze'.
> The project has unused declared artifacts
```

Comment: I get "Execution failed for task ':app:analyze'. > Project does not have the java plugin applied." If I add "apply plugin: 'java'" then I'm told its not compatible with the existing android application plugin. any ideas?

Comment: It sounds like it's something specific with the Android application plugin.  I wish I could help, but I have no experience with Android!

Comment: The plugin has bugs, like for instance when you have static call to a dependency, not taken into account.

Comment: this seems to be deprecated for the linter plugin

Answer (score 1):

*Editor's Note: This answer is out of date. Please see [the top answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19379517/how-to-find-remove-unused-dependencies-in-gradle/37583197#37583197).*

You can try the [com.github.nullstress.dependency-analysis](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.github.nullstress.dependency-analysis) Gradle plugin

**Build script snippet for use in all Gradle versions:**

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath "com.github.nullstress:DependencyAnalysisPlugin:1.0.3"
  }
}

apply plugin: "com.github.nullstress.dependency-analysis"
```

**Build script snippet for new, incubating, plugin mechanism introduced in Gradle 2.1:**

```
plugins {
  id "com.github.nullstress.dependency-analysis" version "1.0.3"
}
```

Also, there is a thread ([Is there a Gradle equivalent of "mvn dependency:analyze"?](http://forums.gradle.org/gradle/topics/is_there_a_gradle_equivalent_of_mvn_dependency_analyze)) in the Gradle forum about this.

Comment: This plugin seems to be a dead project... at least with the current Gradle version.

Answer (score 1):

It might not be exactly what you are looking for, but at least for me, the most comfortable way of doing this without adding any plugins on top or anything else is to highlight the gradle dependency, do a right-click, go to **Git -> Show History For Selection** and then go to the GitHub link to see what that dependency was added for, if it doesn't make sense anymore, just remove it.

Of course this still implies that you have to careful about it, but depending on the project it might be the fastest option.

Answer (score 0):

The projects on most of the historical answers are dead, but [gradle-dependency-analyze](https://github.com/wfhartford/gradle-dependency-analyze) appears to be alive as of 2016-05-30.

Comment: I see them making changes to nebula-lint a couple weeks ago.