# I want to fail a gradle build if there are unused dependencies

Tags: gradle, dependencies, continuous-integration, build.gradle, dependency-management

Exactly what the title says.

I've inherited a legacy project using gradle and the interdependence of modules is giving me a headache. Is there a plugin/process/black magic that'll fail the build on unused dependencies?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find\remove unused dependencies in gradle](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19379517/how-to-find-remove-unused-dependencies-in-gradle)

Comment: I'll give that a bash

Answer (score 2):

Not a direct answer, but closely related.

With DepClean, you can break a Maven build if there are unused dependencies

See https://github.com/ASSERT-KTH/depclean

Comment: There is also a `depclean-gradle-plugin` in the GitHub repo, currently not available from Maven Central but can be built from source. It has a Gradle task called `depclean` which supports boolean parameters `failIfUnusedDirect`, `failIfUnusedTransitive`, and `failIfUnusedInherited`.