# Remove unused part of external library

Tags: android, facebook, analytics, android-proguard, facebook-analytics

I am using

`compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'`

In my Android project just to track Facebook download, but it increases size of my app by 400Kb, which is huge for me.

How can I remove Facebook icons used in lib in release-build using pro-guard or anything else?

For better understanding attaching my apk distribution:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should use proguard to achieve this. Here is a similar question 
[How do I remove unused resources from third-party libraries I’ve included on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33112527/how-do-i-remove-unused-resources-from-third-party-libraries-i-ve-included-on-and)