# How to track unused dependencies by Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I need  a way to analyze my project and shows dependencies which are not used. I know about dependency:analyzer. but it doesn't seem to be compatible with Android plugin.
Any hint ?

Comment: [This thead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37583197/4168607) may help

Comment: @ADM I will take a look ..

Answer (score -3):

List gradle dependecies like this:

```
gradle module_name:dependencies
```

Or if you using gradle wrapper:

```
 ./gradlew module_name:dependencies
```

Replace 'module_name' to your project module.

You can also generate HTML raport:
Add this plugin:

```
  apply plugin: 'project-report'
```

And run:

```
./gradlew htmlDependencyReport
```

Comment: I don't need to list dependencies .. I need to monitor which one is not used. we have very big project and from time to time we analyze dependencies to be sure we are shipping un-used libraries ..